# Redefine \psq and \psqq to refrain from inserting a space after page number

Tags: macros, biblatex

The Biblatex manual tells me about the \psq-command: "The spacing inserted between the suffix and the page number may be modified by redefining the macro
\sqspace. The default is an unbreakable interword space."

I want this space removed, but don't no how to redefine the macro.

So I want

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, ngerman, headsepline]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\space}

\usepackage[
backend=biber, 
style=authoryear-icomp, 
ibidpage=true, 
natbib, 
ibidtracker=true, 
idemtracker=true, 
maxbibnames=9, 
maxcitenames=2, 
dashed=false]
{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite[1\psq]{Tylor}

\end{document}
```

to create 
"Tylor 1871, S. 1f."
instead of
"Tylor 1871, S. 1 f."

Answer (score 1):

Now that was easy:

```
\renewcommand*{\sqspace}{}
```

does the job.